# Validate a unique input field from a foreign key

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

i have a table `rubriqueintermediare` with two fields `rubriqueId` and `rubriqueintermediareId` which is a foreign key from the table `Rubrique`.

My table `Rubriqueintermediare` have a listbox of the `libelle` field from the `rubrique` table.

When I add a new rubriqueintermediare I mustn't add an existing one in the rubriqueintermediare list.

How could I do this validation when I have just `rubriqueintermediareId` and `rubriqueId` in the table `rubriqueintermediare` which are auto incremented in my sql server.
ther is my methode add in the controller of rubriqueintermediare:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, RubriqueIntermediareVM vm)
    {
        try
        {
            ViewData["CodeRubrique"] = new SelectList(RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>(), "RubriqueId", "CODELIBELLE");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                RubriqueIntermediareVM rubi = ServiceApplicatif.Save(vm);
                IEnumerable<RubriqueVM> rubrique = RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>() as IEnumerable<RubriqueVM>;
            }
            DataCache dataCache = new DataCache(CurrentSecurityContext.TenantID);
            dataCache.DropDataCache<RubriqueIntermediareVM>();
            return Json(new[] { vm }.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggerRubriqueIntermediare.Error(string.Format("Exception : {0}", ex.Message.ToString()));
            throw new Exception("Erreur lors de l'enregistrement.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of _describing_ the code, could you _show_ us a short code example?

Comment: there is my methode add in the controller of Rubriqueintermediare:

Comment: if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    RubriqueIntermediareVM rubi = ServiceApplicatif.Save(vm);
                    IEnumerable<RubriqueVM> rubrique = RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>() as IEnumerable<RubriqueVM>;
                }
                DataCache dataCache = new DataCache(CurrentSecurityContext.TenantID);
                dataCache.DropDataCache<RubriqueIntermediareVM>();
                return Json(new[] { vm }.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));

Comment: Please edit your post to include the code. We can't easily read code in the comments.

Comment: okey @gunr2171 i have to add to my save () methode a validation test . i musn't add (from my listbox )a new exisiting Rubriqueintermediare

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this validation into your database

In store procedure

```sql
if exists( select Count(id) 
           from Rubriqueintermediare 
           where @name=rubricname) -- Assuming rubricname is column  
begin
    --return field as you want 
END
Else
Begin
    --Insert as you want
End
```

Comment: i have in my RUBRIQUEINTERMEDIARE table just RUBRIQUEID and RUBRIQUEINTERMEDIAREID i haven't any other field